# Batch converting AIFF to WAV

Tags: macos, batch, wav

I have a few dozen AIF files that I need to convert to WAV. I have converted a few by opening them in Audacity and exporting them to WAV, but this is very slow. I would like to convert them all in batch. Is there a way to do this on OS X?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you want to go for a shell solution, you can do it with `ffmpeg`.

- Option 1: [download `ffmpeg`](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html) and extract the executable `ffmpeg` file. Copy it to a directory that is in your executable path, e.g. `/usr/bin`.

  ```
  sudo cp ~/Downloads/ffmpeg /usr/bin/ffmpeg
  sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/ffmpeg
  ```
- Option 2: Use [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) and `brew install ffmpeg`.

Now, in the folder with the AIF files, run this:

```
for f in *.aiff; do ffmpeg -i "$f" "${f%.aiff}.wav"; done
```

Comment: This worked, thanks! Is there any way I can add compression?

Comment: What kind of compression do you have in mind? WAV usually stores uncompressed PCM audio. ADPCM is sometimes used. You can also put MP3 data in a WAV container. Use the `ffmpeg -i input.aiff -c:a adpcm_ms output.wav`, for example, for Microsoft ADPCM. You can check `ffmpeg -encoders` for all encoders supported.

Comment: `brew install ffmpeg` is quicker than all of the downloading and modding the app.

Comment: @AbsoluteƵERØ True, I added that option.

Comment: slightly simpler command: `find . -name "*.aiff" -exec ffmpeg -i {} {}.wav \;`

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to convert between the two formats using iTunes instead of manually writing something yourself:

```
1.Open iTunes Preferences. 
Windows: Choose Edit > Preferences. 
Mac: Choose iTunes > Preferences.
2.Click the General button, then click the Importing Settings… button in the lower section of the window.
3.From the Import Using pop-up menu, choose the encoding format that you want to convert the song to, then click OK to save the settings.
4.Select one or more songs in your library, then from the File > Create New Version menu, choose one of the following (the menu item changes to show what's selected in your Importing preferences): 
Create MP3 version
Create AAC version
Create AIFF version
Create WAV version
Create Apple Lossless version
```

Source: http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1550

Comment: But this requires that you load the files into itunes. If you're using something like sound samples, that's not necessarily what you want to do, especially if you have itunes set to keep files organized.